# Form submit does not close the form and reload to the homepage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, elementor

I have a problem setting up a form on my website.
I want to add two separate forms on my website, which i did, using some HTML & css.
Thoses forms need to send informations to a webhook -> it also works (since it's collected)
BUT as soon as i press submit, it redirect to the main page of the website, so no conversion (which is a shame) and a very bad input from me.
Please, lend me your intelligence, since i must be the best idiot there is.

```
<form name='myForm' data-form-id='IdFromWebhook' action='WebhookLink' method='post' onsubmit="return false">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="form-group text_box">
        <label for='EMAIL_ADDRESS'>E-mail: </label><input id='insightly_email' name='email' type='text' required>
     </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group text_box">
            <label for='FIRST_NAME'>First name: </label><input id='insightly_firstName' name='firstName' type='text' required>
     </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group text_box">
            <label for='LAST_NAME'>Last Name: </label><input id='insightly_lastName' name='lastName' type='text' required>
     </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="form-group text_box">
<label for='Language__c'>Choose a language: </label>
<select id='insightly_language' name='language' required><option value='EN'>EN</option><option value='FR'>FR</option><option value='DE'>DE</option></select>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Bouton d'envoi-->
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center"><input class="btn_three" type='submit' value='Submit'></div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` this will stops redirect:

```
formReference.onsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefualt()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips !
But it completely cancel the submit button, which is blocking me, sadly

Answer (score 0):

I stupidly found the right answer, i had to specify URLs for the success or error pages.

It was an insightly form.